# Java error, duplicate local variable

Tags: java, variables, duplicates, local

I'm trying to debug a portion of code for an assignment (I'm still very new to Java) and have combed through many resources to solve this conflict but still can't quite work it out.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Enter 'A' for option A or 'B' for option B.");
      String input = keyboard.next();
      input.toLowerCase();
      input.charAt(0);  
    }
    while ((input != "a") || (input != "b"));
}
```

I always get a Duplicate Local Variable error with the input String.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

replace

```
String input = keyboard.next();
```

with

```
input = keyboard.next();
```

If you put a `String` before the variable name it is a declaration. And you can declare a variable name only once in a scope.

Comment: I don't understand Java. Shouldn't the inner 'input' is in while block scope. Whereas outer 'input' is in main() block. Why do they belong in same scope?

Comment: @ScottChu I agree that this is very weird. It looks like Java doesn't allow variable shadowing

Answer (score 5):

You have declared the `input` variable twice. You will need to change this line:

```
String input = keyboard.next();
```

to this:

```
input = keyboard.next();
```

Also, this code will most likely not work:

```
((input != "a") || (input != "b"))
```

In Java, Strings are compared using the `.equals()` method, so this line:

```
((input != "a") || (input != "b"))
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
((!input.equals("a")) || (!input.equals("b")))
```

Comment: Interesting.  I thought that anytime `{}` is used a new scope is created which would allow for both input Strings to be created.  That's not the case?

Comment: @Atlos: The *problem* is that when one nests scopes, as above, the variables declared within the outer scope will still be visible in the inner scopes. This causes confusion to the compiler, since as far as it is concerned, the variable already exists. You could do something like so though: `{...{String str = ...}... String str = ...`. This should work though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated, it's definately something to make note of for future reference

Comment: @npinti: I can't agree with you, nor agree with Java Compiler if that's really what it does. In most of the programming language, when there're same-name variables defined among different scopes, it always use innermost scope's declaration first. If Java is not this case, I can only say Java is a "weird" programming language. >"<

Answer (score 1):

Yoy've duplicated `String input` declaration. Once is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Enter 'A' for option A or 'B' for option B.");
      input = keyboard.next();
      input.toLowerCase();
      input.charAt(0);  
    }
    while ((input != "a") || (input != "b"));
}
```

The problem is you are declaring input inside `do{}` again.
So it should just be

`input=keyboard.next();`

Comment: Also this, `while ((input != "a") || (input != "b"))`, is also not good, since it compares references, not String content. It's OK to see this in the original poster's code, but not in an answerer's code since there is no sense propagating bad code without correcting and explaining, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `input` variable twice . Inside the `main` method declare `input` only once. Use the following code inside `do {}`:

```
input = keyboard.next(); instead of  String input = keyboard.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not how you hide the variables.

Here is what I mean

```
private static String input = null;    
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Enter 'A' for option A or 'B' for option B.");
      String input = keyboard.next();
      input.toLowerCase();
      input.charAt(0);  
    }
    while ((input != "a") || (input != "b"));
}
```

Comment: Also this, `while ((input != "a") || (input != "b"))`, is also not good, since it compares references, not String content. It's OK to see this in the original poster's code, but not in an answerer's code since there is no sense propagating bad code without correcting and explaining, right?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a duplicate local variable if you have declared the variable twice, here in your code you have declared the **input variable** twice.
That is why you received that error.