# Duplicate local variable x

Tags: java

I am having an issue with the for loop saying it is a duplicate local variable? I am still trying to learn about this and I have looked into it as far as my knowledge can take me to find the answer on my own so I am now asking you all. If you don't mind I would like an explanation to why it doesn't work?

```
int x = 3;
String name = "Dirk";
x = x * 17;
System.out.print("x is " + x);
double d = Math.random();

while (x > 12) {
    x = x - 1;
}

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1) {
    System.out.print("x is now " + x);
}

if (x == 10) {
    System.out.print("x must be 10");
} else {
    System.out.print("x isn't 10");
}
if ((x < 3) & (name.equals("Dirk"))) {
    System.out.println("Gently");
}
```

Comment: you declare x two time `int x = 3;` first line and in the for loop `for (int x = 0; ..) {` to solve your issue just use `for (x = 0;..` without type, or use another variable name in the loop `for (int y = 0;..` for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java error, duplicate local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823885/java-error-duplicate-local-variable)

Comment: > In Java, you CANNOT have 2 different local/parameter variables with the same name in the same (overlapping) scope

you define **int x = 3;** in first line and again inside the loop **for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)**

Comment: Ah, Okay! I am thinking the best one to use is the one from the start because I want it to continue down and to continue through the program? I am using the Head First Java book to learn what I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the second declaration and reassignation of `x` in your `for` loop:

```
for ( ; x < 10; x++) {
    System.out.print("x is now " + x);
}
```

Otherwise you can simplify some instructions like this:

`x++` instead of `x = x + 1`

`x*=19` instead of `x = x * 19`

Comment: Thank you Idriss!